# Input type text height and padding

Tags: html, css

I just run into a very weird issue.
I am adapting some html file (actually, ftl) to a template. I have been given a static html and css files. After apply everithing properly, my inputs don't look as they should. I have checked very carefully the computed style and they are right, as you can see in the image below.
[image]

The original input has height 18px and padding top and bottom of 6px, so must be 18+12=30px height. Altough, what I get is an input with height 6px plus padding top 6px and padding bottom 6px so 6+6+6=18px.

Can somebody explain what is happening here?? BTW I am using safari in both cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you used Firebug or similar to inspect the element in the browser? That should tell you where the style that is being applied is coming from. Are you using a rest.css stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that in both case it compute the same styles, as you can see in the image I posted. I am not using any reset.css or similar.

Comment: are these two screenshots "before and after" your changes?

Comment: How do the containers/parents of input elements look like? Can you post some code?

Comment: The box-sizing property has been set to border-box in the window on the right.  Is Safari adding this when you set the height or are you?

Comment: Are you using quirks or standards mode? Browsers use different box-sizings for the two modes.